# Why This session Variable setting blank after random amount of time

Tags: php, session

My php session variable automatically setting blank value after random amount of time. 
for example; If I logged in to my Website then $_SESSION["uid"] will setting in my PHP session. and it redirect to the dashboard. In my dashboard page fetching user information according to this session variable. After that i just minimized this browser window(Google Chrome) and i just opened another browser(Mozilla Firefox) and browse some other websites for 20 or more than 20 minutes, Then I Came back to my minimized Dashboard page(Google Chrome) and If I refresh the page then the $_SESSION["uid"] will set to blank.

My codes something like this

when setting session variable

```
  <?php
   session_start();

   function to_set_session_variable(){
   $_SESSION["uid"]=10;
   session_write_close();
   }

   ?>
```

Codes inside Dashboard page

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    $uid=$_SESSION["uid"];
    get_user_data($uid);

     -----------------------------------
     -----------------------------------
     -----------------------------------
    ?>
```

Comment: That is because PHP needs to clear out sessions that are not in use anymore. It does that at regular intervals of time. You can save the session values in database like redis if you want to set custom timeout as opposed to default storage in file by php.

Answer (score 3):

Sessions in PHP have a default timeout which is 1440 seconds (24 minutes). This can be changed in the `php.ini` by editing the `session.gc_maxlifetime`.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime